# Need help in vlookup in linux using awk

Tags: linux, unix

I have two data files. One is having 1600 rows and the other one is having 2 million rows(tab delimited files). I need to vlookup between these two files. Please see below example for the expected output and kindly let me know if it's possible. I've tried using awk, but couldn't get the expected result.

File 1(small file)
BC1 10 100
BC2 20 200
BC3 30 300

File 2(large file)
BC1 XYZ
BC2 ABC
BC3 DEF

Expected Output:
BC1 10 100 XYZ
BC2 20 200 ABC
BC3 30 300 DEF

I also tried the join command. It is taking forever to complete. Please help me find a solution. Thanks

Comment: Show what you tried, and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Commands for your output:

1. awk '{print $1}' *file | sort | uniq -d > out.txt
2. for i in $(cat out.txt)
       do
            grep "$i" large_file >> temp.txt
       done
   sort -g -t 1 temp.txt > out1.txt
3. sort -g -t 1 out.txt > out2.txt
4. paste out1.txt out2.txt | awk '{print $1 $2 $3 $5}'

Commands for Vlookup

Store 1st and 2nd column in file1 file2 respectively

cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -d   ### for records which are present in both files

cat file1 file2 | sort | uniq -u   ### for records which are unique and not present in bulk file

Answer (score 0):

This awk script will scan line by line each file, and will try to match the number in the BC column. Once matched, it will print all the columns.
If one of the files does not contain one of the numbers, it will be skipped in both files and will search for the next one. It will loop until one of the files ends.
The script also accepts any number of columns per file and any number of files, as long as the first column is BC and a number.
**This awk script assumes that the files are ordered from minor to major number in the BC column (like in your example)**. Otherwise it will not work.

To execute the script, run this command:

```
awk -f vlookup.awk smallfile bigfile
```

The vlookup.awk file will have this content:

```
BEGIN {files=1;lines=0;maxlines=0;filelines[1]=0; 

#Number of columns for SoD, PRN, reference file

col_bc=1;

#Initialize variables
bc_now=0;

new_bc=0;

end_of_process=0;

aux="";
text_result="";
}
{
if(FILENAME!=ARGV[1])exit;

no_bc=0;
new_bc=0;

#Save number of columns
NFields[1]=NF;

#Copy reference file data
for(j=0;j<=NF;j++) 
{
    file[1,j]=$j;
}

#Read lines from file
for(i=2;i<ARGC;i++)
{
    ret=getline < ARGV[i];
    if(ret==0) exit; #END OF FILE reached
    #Copy columns to file variable
    for(j=0;j<=NF;j++) 
    {
        file[i,j]=$j;
    }
    #Save number of columns
    NFields[i]=NF;

}

#Check that all files are in the same number
for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++) 
{
    bc[i]=file[i,col_bc];
    bc[i]=sub("BC","",file[i,col_bc]);
    if(bc[i]>bc_now) {bc_now=bc[i];new_bc=1;}       
}

#One or more files have a new number
if (new_bc==1)
{
    for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
    {
        while(bc_now!=file[i,col_bc])
        {
            #Read next line from file
            if(i==1) ret=getline; #File 1 is the reference file
            else ret=getline < ARGV[i];
            if(ret==0) exit; #END OF FILE reached
            #Copy columns to file variable
            for(j=0;j<=NF;j++) 
            {
                file[i,j]=$j;
            }
            #Save number of columns
            NFields[i]=NF;
            #Check if in current file data has gone to next number
            if(file[i,col_bc]>bc_now) 
            {
                no_bc=1;
                break;  
            }
            #No more data lines to compare, end of comparison
            if(FILENAME!=ARGV[1])
            {
                exit;
            }
        }
        #If the number is not in a file, the process to realign must be restarted to the next number available (Exit for loop)
        if (no_bc==1) {break;}
    }
    #If the number is not in a file, the process to realign must be restarted to the next number available (Continue while loop)
    if (no_bc==1) {next;}

} 


#Number is aligned
for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++)
{
    for(j=2;j<=NFields[i];j++) {

        #Join colums in text_result variable
        aux=sprintf("%s %s",text_result,file[i,j]);
        text_result=sprintf("%s",aux);

    }
}
printf("BC%d%s\n",bc_now,text_result)
#Reset text variables
aux="";
text_result=""; 



}
```

Comment: I think you're putting way too much work into this. Based on the sample info, it's really an awk one-liner.

Comment: This is a script I already had done for something else. It just took me 5 minutes to do some minor modifications and post it here

Answer (score 0):

> I also tried the join command. It is taking forever to complete.
>   Please help me find a solution.

It's improbable that you'll find a solution (scripted or not) that's faster than the compiled `join` command. If you can't wait for `join` to complete, you need more powerful hardware.