# Why using awk in bash like vlookup in Excel give empty output file?

Tags: join, awk, vlookup

The good using of `awk` is still unclear for me, but I know it will be useful for what I want.

I have two files, both are tab delimited:

`transcriptome.txt` (with billion of lines):

```
 >TRINITY_DN261_c0_g1_i1    GATATTTATCCGAATATTCAATATGAT
 >TRINITY_DN299_c0_g1_i1    GGACACGGGCCTCAAGCCAAGTCAAAACCACCACAAAG
 >TRINITY_DN216_c0_g1_i1    GTTCAATATTCAATGACTGAAGGGCCCGCTGATTTTCCCCTATAAA
 >TRINITY_DN220_c0_g1_i1    GGGAGATAATAACAATGATAACACACAAAATTCCAATG
```

`selected_genes.txt` (thousands of lines):

```
 >TRINITY_DN261_c0_g1_i1    1
 >TRINITY_DN220_c0_g1_i1    0
```

I want this output (first column of `selected_genes.txt` and second column of `transcriptome.txt`):

```
 >TRINITY_DN261_c0_g1_i1    GATATTTATCCGAATATTCAATATGAT
 >TRINITY_DN220_c0_g1_i1    GGGAGATAATAACAATGATAACACACAAAATTCCAATG
```

Usually I use the `vlookup` function in Excel.
I try to obtain my result with `awk`, like in many threads ([stackexchange1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257002/vlookup-work-in-awk-on-linux), [stackexchange2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502289/linux-vlookup-using-one-file-to-another), [stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507981/need-help-in-vlookup-in-linux-using-awk),[stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354757/vlookup-using-awk-command), [stackoverflow3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52358792/vlookup-using-awk-command-2-and-printing-into-desired-form?noredirect=1&lq=1), and others..)

So I tried to used advices from these threads, but my output is either blank, either it's only a copy of my `selected_genes.txt` file.

I checked, my 2 files are in `UTF-8`, with `CRLF`. Also,

```
awk '{print $1}' `transcriptome.txt`
awk '{print $1}' `selected_genes.txt`
```

Give me well the first column of my files, so the problem didn't come from them.

Here is what I tried:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1]=$1; next}; $1 in a {print a[$2]}' selected_genes.txt transcriptome.txt > output.txt
# Blank result

awk -F 'FNR==NR{var[$1]=$1;next;}{print var[$1]FS$2}' selected_genes.txt transcriptome.txt > output.txt
# Blank result

awk 'NR == FNR{a[$1] = $2;next}; {print $1, $1 in a?a[$1]: "NA"}' selected_genes.txt transcriptome.txt > output.txt
# Print only transcriptome.txt with first column and NAs

awk -F, 'FNR==NR{var[$1]=$1}FNR!=NR{print(var[$2]","$1)}' selected_genes.txt transcriptome.txt > output.txt
# Print only selected_genes.txt
```

I didn't achieve to produce the wanted output. 
Any advices to explain me what is the problem with my code will be grateful.

Comment: You mentioned that your 2 files end with CRLF. Before using UNIX tools such as awk or join on them you should run `dos2unix` or similar to avoid any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk classic. Hash the *thousands of lines* gene file to a hash (`a`) to not waste all the memory and lookup `$1` from *billions of lines* transcriptome file:

```
$ awk '
    # { sub(/\r$/,"") }    # uncomment to remove Windows style line-endings.
    NR==FNR{a[$1]          # hash $1 of genes file to a
    next
}
($1 in a) {                # lookup from transcriptome
    print
}' genes transcriptome     # mind the order
>TRINITY_DN261_c0_g1_i1    GATATTTATCCGAATATTCAATATGAT
>TRINITY_DN220_c0_g1_i1    GGGAGATAATAACAATGATAACACACAAAATTCCAATG
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Unfortunately, my output is still blank.. 
I added a '> output.txt' after the 2 files. Maybe this is problematic ?
or may be I need to put something after "print" ?

Comment: No, this is all you need. If the output is blank then none of the first fields from the 2nd file exist in the 1st file. Check if there are any blanks in either file rather than just tabs between the fields.

Comment: Thanks to your comment in my post @EdMorton, this work well now ! Thanks !
Also, I see this awk command deleted the duplicates "genes", I didn't excepted that but it's ok !

Comment: Which file had duplicates? If duplicates are lost, probably the `genes` file? But that would not make any difference?

Comment: EdMorton Yes, yes, this is does exactly what I want.
@James Brown Thanks for your answer. After run dos2unix (EdMorton comments in my post), your command work perfectly. In my selected_genes file, I had 9840 genes (in my original file). In the output I have 9820 genes. I see after this happen because I had 20 genes in duplicate in my original file (without knowing it before..). So apparently the awk command remove also the duplicates (but it's ok for me).
Thanks again you both !!

Comment: Another way to fix the newlines is to add `{sub(/\r$/,"")}` to the beginning of the script. That removes the `\r` from `\r\n` line-endings. Using GNU awk I usually set the `RS="\r?\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better tool in the box than `awk` for this sort of file merge on a common field, especially for big files: [join(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html)

```
$ join -t $'\t' -11 -21 -o 0,2.2 \
   <(sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 selected_genes.txt) \
   <(sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 transcriptome.txt)
>TRINITY_DN220_c0_g1_i1 GGGAGATAATAACAATGATAACACACAAAATTCCAATG
>TRINITY_DN261_c0_g1_i1 GATATTTATCCGAATATTCAATATGAT
```

The only caveat is that the files to be joined have to be sorted on the join column, hence the uses of `sort`.

In database terms, it does an `INNER JOIN` of the two files - for each row of the first file, every row of the second file with a matching join column results in one row of output. The `-o 0,2.2` makes those lines be the join column and the second column of the second file.

---

Another interesting option:

```
$ grep -F -f <(sed -e 's/[^\t]*$//' selected_genes.txt) transcriptome.txt 
>TRINITY_DN261_c0_g1_i1 GATATTTATCCGAATATTCAATATGAT
>TRINITY_DN220_c0_g1_i1 GGGAGATAATAACAATGATAACACACAAAATTCCAATG
```

will, [very efficiently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), show just the lines of `transcriptome.txt` that have the first column of a line in `selected_genes.txt` appear in them. This is faster than the other approaches by a large margin in my tests.

Comment: Not sure why you'd think that join + cut + 2 sorts + bashisms + pipes would be better than a simple `awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a'`. That grep would need more work to be robust, as written you'd get false matches, e.g. a key ending in `i17` being matched by one ending in `i1`.

Comment: @EdMorton If the sample input in OP's question is typical, that's not going to be an issue with the grep approach. And if that's not an issue, it runs almost instantaneously on my test data with 2000 lines in the selected file and 4 million in the transcript file on a very anemic laptop. The join and awk approaches are within a couple of seconds of each other (Interestingly, sorting the files ahead of time doesn't have any significant impact; the sorting and joining can done in parallel on different cores). Of the two, I'll use the one using a tool doing exactly what it was designed for.

Comment: As for 'bashisms'... well, OP tagged the question `bash`. They're fair game to use.

Comment: They're all fair game to use but there's a lot of moving parts, it's non-portable, and you're running `sort` and, probably less importantly, `join` on a file that the OP told us is billions of lines long, not just 4 million lines long!

Answer (score 0):

your code:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$1; next}; $1 in a {print a[$2]}'
```

will not work since you're trying to print `a[$2]` which doesn't exist.

Change to

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' selected_genes.txt transcriptome.txt
```

which should give you the expected output

The second expression is shorthand for `($1 in a) {print $0}`